# Inserir <li> e <a> via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando DOM e estou com dificuldade em inserir um novo `<li>` e `<a>` em uma determinada `<ul>`.

Consegui inserir um novo `<li>` utilizando o código abaixo, porém não consegui ter sucesso em inserir um novo `<a>` nesse novo `<li>`:

Gostaria de inserir o seguinte elemento nesse novo `<li>`:

```
<a href ="https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/" target = "_blank">PyCharm</a>
```

Segue o código:

```
function insereLi(){

    //Adicionar um novo elemento a uma arvore
    //Criar um novo elemento e o armazena em uma variavel
    var newEl = document.createElement('li');

    //Criar um nó de texto e armazenar em uma variável
    var newText = document.createTextNode('Pycharm');

    //Anexar novo nó de texto ao elemento criado
    newEl.appendChild(newText);

    // Localiza a posição onde o elemento deve ser posicionado
    var position = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1];

    //insere o novo elemento em sua posição
    position.appendChild(newEl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o html que está a tentar gerar, falta criar dinamicamente a tag `<a>`, também através da função `createElement`. Depois os atributos desse `<a>` são colocados utilizando [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Exemplo:

```js
function insereLi(){
    var newEl = document.createElement('li');
    var newA = document.createElement('a'); //a tag <a> que faltava
    var newText = document.createTextNode('Pycharm');
    var position = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    
    //os atributos do <a>
    newA.setAttribute("href", "https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/");
    newA.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    newA.appendChild(newText); //colocar o texto no <a>
    newEl.appendChild(newA); //e o <a> dentro do <li>
    position.appendChild(newEl);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", insereLi);
```

```html
<button>Insere Li</button><br><br>

Lista
<ul>
  <li>Um item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Eu estava me perguntando porque usar `document.createTextNode()` ao invés de simplesmente usar a propriedade `innerHTML`, já que parece mais trabalhoso e até mais custoso pensando logicamente (mais um objeto criado), e vi agora essa resposta: [Is there any major difference between innerHTML and using createTextNode to fill a span?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13122927/8133067). Tinha pensado em colocar na minha resposta uma versão que também adicionasse o tag `<a>` usando o método `createElement()`, mas não fiz, e você respondeu quase junto e fez assim. Votei na sua resposta! ;-)

Comment: @PedroGaspar innerHTML é naturalmente mais simples mas eu optei por manter o estilo que o AP tinha. Ainda assim tem uma ou outra diferença subtil que pode ou não ser relevante, como por exemplo injeção de JS.

Comment: Ah sim, eu também pensei em usar o `createTextNode` para seguir o mesmo estilo, só que optei por mostrar uma forma diferente, entretanto queria mostrar a forma com `createTextNode` também, mas felizmente você supriu essa necessidade! Posso acrescentar essas informações sobre a diferença entre os dois na minha resposta ou você irá adicionar na sua?

Comment: @PedroGaspar Assim como eu mais tarde pensei em colocar uma alternativa com `innerHTML` mas depois quando reparei já lá estava a sua resposta com essa alternativa :D. Esteja à vontade para colocar as diferenças, que é algo que enriquece a resposta.

Comment: Bom dia @Isac. Consegui implementar com sucesso sua colaboração na minha primeira pagina de estudo. 
https://maxwneto.github.io/
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
function insereLi(texto)
{
  // Localiza o elemento <ul> através do seu id, usando getElementById().
  var minhaLista = document.getElementById('minhaListaDesordenada');

  // Cria um novo elemento <li> no documento.
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  // Informa o texto do novo elemento <li>.
  newLi.textContent = texto;

  // Insere o novo elemento <li> na lista <ul>.
  minhaLista.appendChild(newLi);
}

function insereLiComLink(url, descricao)
{
  // Localiza o elemento <ul> através do seu id, usando querySelector().
  var minhaLista = document.querySelector('#minhaListaDesordenada');

  // Cria um novo elemento <li> no documento.
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  // Informa o texto do novo elemento <li>.
  newLi.innerHTML = '<a href ="' + url + '" target = "_blank">' + descricao + '</a>';

  // Insere o novo elemento <li> na lista <ul>.
  minhaLista.appendChild(newLi);
}

// Testa as duas funções criando mais 3 elementos <li> à lista <ul>.
insereLi('Item dinâmico 1')
insereLiComLink('https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/', 'PyCharm')
insereLi('Item dinâmico 3')
```

```html
<ul id="minhaListaDesordenada">
<li>Item fixo</li>
</ul>
```

A primeira função, `insereLi()`, insere um elemento `<li>` apenas com texto, e ela usa o método `document.getElementById()` ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) para achar a lista `<ul>` pelo seu id (que deve ser único), e depois usa a propriedade `textContent` ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) do novo elemento `<li>`, já que estamos inserindo somente texto.

Já a segunda função, `insereLiComLink()`, recebe um URL e uma descrição, para montar um elemento `<a>` dentro do elemento `<li>`. Nessa função usei o `document.querySelector()` ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)) para achar a lista `<ul>` pelo seu id, para mostrar uma alternativa. Aqui usei a propriedade `innerHTML` ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)) para acrescentar o elemento `<a>` dentro do novo elemento `<li>`.

A [resposta do Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341334/86952) mostra como adicionar o elemento `<a>` ao `<li>` usando `document.createElement()` e `document.createTextNode`.

Pelas pesquisas que eu fiz ([What Is A Text Node, Its Uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17195868/8133067)), porque eu tinha essa dúvida e a resposta do Isac me fez pensar sobre isso, algumas diferenças entre usar `element.innerHTML` e `document.createTextNode()`+`element.appendChild(textNode)` são:

- A propriedade `innerHTML` é mais recente e o jeito "antigo" era usar o `createTextNode()`;
- Por isso mesmo, o método `createTextNode()` pode ser mais compatível com a maioria dos navegadores;
- Eu achava que usar o método `createTextNode()` seria mais custoso, por criar um novo objeto, mas o que a propriedade `innerHTML` faz no fundo é analisar (*parse*) o HTML e criar os nós necessários, inclusive os nós de texto, porque o [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) (Document Object Model) "organiza" todo seu conteúdo como ramos de uma árvore, que terminam em [nós](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), e cada nó contém objetos, então no fundo, objetos serão criados de qualquer forma, mesmo para um simples texto dentro de uma tag;
- Justamente pelo fato da propriedade `innerHTML` analisar (*parse*) o HTML, o uso dela pode causar um [risco de segurança](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations), se forem usados valores recebidos de input do usuário para prencher a propriedade, porque ela pode ser usada para injeção de scripts.

Comment: Bom dia @Pedro Gaspar. Muito obrigado pela colaboração. Consegui entender sua solução mas mantive no código a solução do Isac por ser o que eu havia pensado mas não consegui evoluir com a solução. Mas é muito bom ter uma segunda linha de raciocinio.  Abraços.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou Max! Mas, aqui a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita (clicando no "sinal de visto", ✓, logo abaixo da seta para baixo), veja essa página: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Então depois aceite a resposta do Isac, por favor (além de tudo você ainda ganha 2 pontos por isso). Aproveite também para visitar a [página de boas-vindas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site.

Comment: Obrigado novamente.